# Programatically updating post featured image appears on frontend only on page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

I am programatically updating the post thumbnail from the **single post page** on the frontend via a form, and also deleting the previous image and its meta data from the database before I upload the new one to keep things clutter free in the DB. Everything works fine, it's just that when the **single post page** gets refreshed on form submit, it still shows the old image. I have to refresh the page one more time manually to display the new featured image.

```
if( !empty( $_FILES['post-image']['name']) && $_FILES['post-image']['error'] == 0 ){

    $old_img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    wp_delete_attachment( $old_img_id, true );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id'. $old_img_id );
    delete_post_thumbnail($post_id);
    
    
    $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = $_FILES['post-image']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['post-image']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . rand(1,1000) . basename( $file );
    
    
    move_uploaded_file( $temp , $uploadfile );
    $filename = basename( $uploadfile );
    
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
    // echo $mime_check = $wp_filetype['ext'];
    
    
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
    );
    require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    
    
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id ); 
    
    $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploadfile );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $metadata );
}
```

And this is how I am displaying the post thumbnail on this page:

```
<img src="<?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) : echo "http://my-site.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/325business_page.jpg"; else : echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/Image placeholder.jpg'; endif; ?>" id="uploaded_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
```

How do I get rid of this old featured image still showing on form submit even after it is supposed to have been deleted from the db? Thank you.

Comment: See this is better

Comment: Ok, so have you checked that the data was actually deleted from the database? and the file on disk was deleted

Comment: What is in `<img src="???"` when you have got the page after the referesh, is it the same name as before the update? Look in the Page Source

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your comment but it was a silly mistake from my side. I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I managed to solve the problem. It appears I was running the post '*updation*' code **after** already grabbing data from the REST API endpoint.

Previously:

- Grab data  from API (was grabbing  old data to populate the page
  below)
- 'Update the post' code (Sincedata was already grabbed, it
  was NOT showing the new edits yet.)

Fix:

- 'Update the post' code first
- Then Grab fresh data